Simple Form is rendering duplicate input field in rails 7
Guys I am trying to render a partial form using a simple_form but I am getting a duplicate input field of same attribute.
This is my form
<%= simple_form_for post, html: { class: "post form" } do |f| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error-message">
      <%= post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.capitalize %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :title, input_html: { autofocus: true } %>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn--secondary" %>
<% end %>


This is my view
<main class="container">
  <%= link_to sanitize("&larr; Back to posts"), posts_path %>

  <div class="header">
    <h1>New post</h1>
  </div>

  <%= render "form", post: @post %>
</main>

This my two model user and post
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
end

This is the rendered html
This is the rendered html
And this is the html source
   <main class="container">
  <a href="/posts">← Back to posts</a>

  <div class="header">
    <h1>New post</h1>
  </div>

  <form class="simple_form post form" id="new_post" novalidate="novalidate" action="/posts" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="LT-RDFbJLW9mnmVCwfb7JtY0ESG6XDlKohmI23eBW78QXdGe39Q1jLTz4rKAlV6ZQQvWSrVedPlPjuj5mv1KxA" autocomplete="off" />

  <div class="input string required post_title"><label class="visually-hidden string required" for="post_title"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Title</label><input class="form__input string required" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="post[title]" id="post_title" /><label class="string required" for="post_title"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Title</label><input autofocus="autofocus" class="string required" type="text" name="post[title]" id="post_title" /></div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Post" class="btn btn--secondary" data-disable-with="Create Post" />
</form>
</main>

I looked at all scss files and went throught simple_form config seems to be all okay.

did you customize your simple form config?

I don't know what happen but after turning on my laptop this morning problem is fixed. I am guessing may I had to restart the rails server but I restarted server few times before . So I really don't know what was wrong and how the problem is solved.

Should be
<%= simple_form_for post, html: { class: "post form" } do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn--secondary" %>
<% end %>

